# Best way to generate all 0-1 matrices that are row stochastic with all column sums positive?

Tags: python, arrays, linear-algebra

I'm trying to efficiently generate the list of all 9-by-3 matrices, where each matrix satisfies the following properties:

1. Every entry is 0 or 1.
2. Every row sum is 1.
3. Every column contains at least one 1.

My first approach was as follows:

1. Generate a list, A, of all 0-1 matrices of size 9-by-3.

   ```
    import numpy as np
    import itertools
    n=9
    k=3
    A=[np.reshape(np.array(i), (n,k)) for i in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat = n*k)]
   ```
2. Extract from the list A those whose row sums are one and whose columns contain at least one positive entry:

   ```
    matrix_list=[]
    N=len(A)
    for k in range(N):
        B=A[k]
        if (np.sum(B,axis=0)>1).all() and (np.sum(B,axis=1)==1).all():
            matrix_list.append(B)
   ```

This approach I believe works, but it is quite inefficient. Could I somehow create my list of matrices by just considering how to generate all possible matrices that result from taking simple matrix, S:

```
    S=np.matrix([[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0]])
```

and create all possible matrices that result from permuting entries in each row, without including the two matrices whose column sums (be it column 0 or column 1) are zero?

Answer (score 0):

A friend not monitoring my question has suggested this, which works:

```
    from itertools import combinations
    matrices=[]
    nine=set(range(9))
    for i in range(1,9):
        for combinationI in combinations(nine,i):
            m=[0]*9
            for cI in combinationI:
                m[cI]=[1,0,0]
            remaining=nine.difference(combinationI)
            for j in range(1,9-i):
                for combinationJ in combinations(remaining,j):
                    matrix=m[:]
                    for cJ in combinationJ:
                        matrix[cJ]=[0,1,0]
                    r=remaining.difference(set(combinationJ))
                    for cR in r:
                        matrix[cR]=[0,0,1]
                    matrices.append(matrix)
```